# I want to sum all price in my database using DSS in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my problem:

for example:

User inputted: 2000 as desired budget

User selected Wedding as desired service type

What are all the combinations of services that can be afforded given the budget?

My initial query is:

```
Select price,service_inclusion, 
           soid, servicetype 
      FROM service_offer where servicetype='Wedding' and SUM(price) = 2000
```

Here are the data in my database.

```
ID   Service_type     Price
1    Wedding           500 
2    Wedding           700      
3    Wedding          1000
4    Wedding           300 
5    Wedding          1000
```

This is what will be the result
either this:

```
4    Wedding  300
2    Wedding  700
3    Wedding  1000
```

Or

```
3   Wedding   1000
5   Wedding   1000
```

Or I can use it random. Can I make it on a query or just I can do it in php code?

Comment: It could be me, but I think it's very unclear what you mean. Could you try to explain your goal a little better?

Comment: here is my initial query: select price, SUM(price) as Total, from service_offer where servicetype='Wedding' . If the customer input 2000 for budget. the system will SUM of the prices that will make it equal to 2000. as stated above it cout be 1000 1000 or it culd be 700 300 1000

Comment: here is my 2nd query but it makes an error: select price,service_inclusion, soid, servicetype from service_offer where servicetype='Wedding' and SUM(price) = 2000

Comment: What does "ganito" mean?  What does DSS mean?  Are you wanting help fixing your second query?  Like Peter stated, please make your main post clearer instead of adding more requests in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly. You want a query to return all possible combinations of items with service type 'Wedding' that will add up to your budget.

This is a difficult problem, basically a variant of the [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

A simple approach might be to get all the values of the items that match 'Wedding' and start subtracting them from your remaining budget until you get to 0 (or close to 0).

You could start with small amounts to get more 'services' into your budget or start with large amounts to have only a few services.

It's probably possible to do this in SQL, but not recommended.

Comment: any other. suggestions that you can give im not a pro. I am just a newbie in php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

@jayboune - I agree with Loopo. It's not an easy problem to solve as you want to consider every possible combination (assuming that you "Wedding" is always included). The processing requirements (memory, time etc) would increase each time a new service was added to the database and be made available.

Probably an easier option (and a better customer experience) would be to present the customer with the available services (including prices) and keep a running total on the page they are using as they choose services they want. Only presenting services which cost less than the remaining budget will make the customer think more about what they *really* want.

Using this method means that the time delay in choosing things will far outweigh any processing delays. And, from a customer point of view, there won't be a long delay before the can actually start doing things

Comment: Is it possible if I will code it? to solve the problem? how? do u have some algo here?

Comment: I'm not going to give you code as I don't have time. However, start off with a form and a couple of fields giving a "maximum budget" and "service type". Once you have this information, you can query the database with something like `select * from service_offer where servicetype='service type' and price<remaining_budget`. Use AJAX calls (check out jQuery for this) to perform the requests, update the remaining budget etc. Feed the request results into a form and, each time an option is selected, update the remaining budget and re-query the database